# Pass arguments to a Bash subshell after its definition

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I'd like to do something like this:

```
(cd "$1" && pwd && many && other && commands) < echo "../path"
```

Which should take the arguments provided and pass them to the subshell. The subshell should then execute.

The important part is that passed arguments are at the end of command line to allow for easy altering because the cursor is at the end of command when user presses the Up arrow.

Comment: A subshell will take the variable just defined in the parent shell. So `(cd "$A" && pwd && many && other && commands)`, `A="NewPath"` then `!-2` or 2 times Up arrow and enter...

Comment: Nice to know that subshell will take the variable just defined in the parent shell. But your command does not work.

Comment: I've tested on a bash 4.3.11. They work. Where did you find they are not working?  Did you set the first time the variable `A` to the old path? Give it a look to the answer below and let me know. Else you can pass parameter to a bash invocation with the option `-c`.

Comment: Sorry. What I meant to say is that it executes the subshell even without var A being set. I need to set the var and run the subshell in one go.

Comment: I supposed you want to reiterate the same command more times changing the pah (for example). So the 1st time is set and after you run it again. BTW you may be interested to know that `CTRL+A` will put the cursor at the beginning of the line you just recalled with the `Up` arrow. There are a lot of keyboard shortcuts for each terminal `;-)`

Comment: That is exactly why. And for the sake of easy changing the "path", I'd like to have it set at the end of the command since it's the default place where cursor appears. I didn't know about CTRL+A (nice) but Home does the same thing but neither solve my problem - imagine the "variable" in the middle of the commands in the subshell.

Comment: It is not possible to answer to each possible case. You presented one and I give you some hints (and working solutions) about it. In the latter case probably the best solution is to write a function on the fly (with or without the subshell it depends from your needs) and then pass the parameters each time different. A CPU usually executes commands in a linear way from left to right... Try to think in this way and it will be more simple to make everything you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bash subshell will inherit the variables of the parent shell (but it will not modify them!).
A simple way is to define you series of command with variables that you define and modify them in the parent shell.

```
MyTempVar="FirstPath"
(cd "$MyTempVar" && pwd && many && other && commands) && unset MyTempVar
MyTempVar="NewPath"
!-2
```

- With `!-2`, if history options are enabled, you will execute the second last command of your history. It is an expansion of the *built-in* history of bash.
- More safe is to enable the `histverify` with `shopt -s histverify` to have a visual confirmation before that the command from the history is processed.
- Again safe it is <kbd>Up</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- With `unset MyTempVar` you can optionally unset the variable `MyTempVar` if you want.

---

You can even create a function or a script and pass the variables to them. 
E.g.

```
TTT(){ (A="$1"; cd "$A" && pwd ;)  }
```

then call

```
TTT MyPath
```

Comment: The functional approach looks promising. But I'm wondering why do I have to enclose the commands in subshell brackets if they are in function already?

Comment: To avoid to modify the value of A in the parent shell. The subshell was your request... :-) BTW you do not need even to set A, as you can read you can use `$1..$n` inside the function. And you need not to use a subshell too. You can do a script and put it executable (`chmod u+x myscript.sh`) somewhere in your path (`$PATH`). When you need to modify the variable in the parent shell you can `source` it, else you can execute it.

Comment: I know that I could create a script but I'd like to avoid that since I know I won't be using created command in the future. Also it's an unnecessary hassle to edit text file. What I was going for when asking about brackets was that when you do `AAA(){ echo $1 && pwd  } ; AAA foo` the shell enters to "input mode". But with `AAA(){ ( echo $1 && pwd ) } ; AAA foo` it doesn't. I find that strange.

Comment: What do you mean for "input mode"?

Comment: Just like when you don't close the quote (") and press Enter. The Bash then awaits for closing quote or Ctrl+D.

Comment: Now I understand. It waits you finish the command (or you asked to have another line or you close bad brackets). You need to put a `;`. In this way`AAA(){ cd $1 && pwd ; }` it is ok. Instead `BBB(){ cd $1 && pwd }` will wait for something. If you add `}` and press enter, when you reload the last command (with the Up key) you will find `BBB(){ cd $1 ; pwd }; }`. Now the first `}` is taken as parameter of `pwd` that gives you no error. Try with `CCC(){ cd $1 ; echo }` then, when asked, with another `}`. After execute it (`CCC mydir`) and it will change directory and print the character `}`.